# How can I read the Caps lock state in Windows Secure Desktop?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, security

I have written a program that needs to read the Caps lock state in Secure Desktop mode. However, neither Control.IsKeyLocked nor the Win32API GetKeyState() can obtain the current Caps lock state.

I think that it does not require administrator privileges to do so because my TextBox is set to password input mode and it displays a warning for the Caps lock state.

Secure desktop is composed of four steps: CreateDesktop(), SwitchDesktop(), Task.Factory.StartNew, and SetThreadDesktop().

And it's CreateDesktop() in my code:

```
Dim New_hDesktop As IntPtr = CreateDesktop("GeekDesk1", IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 0, DESKTOP_ACCESS.GENERIC_ALL, IntPtr.Zero)
```

(It's VB.NET, but all OK with C# and VB)

Using C++ to solve the problem is also acceptable, I can try to convert it to C#, but please do not suggest solutions that require elevated privileges/ or something like drivers, ring 0 works....

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Thank .

I have tried Control.IsKeyLocked and Win32API GetKeyState() to get the real-time Caps lock status in Secure Desktop mode.

Comment: Looking through the KeyPass source that uses also a Secure Desktop it seems they/he uses GetKeyState for this in that context also. Have a look at [this](https://github.com/dlech/KeePass2.x/blob/a1555354f2e262cf185605426a79d216558f1243/KeePass/UI/UIUtil.cs#L2742) maybe you see a difference how GetKeyState is used there and what you did.

Comment: The Keypass source code does not seem to use this API while in secure desktop mode (I haven't tracked it completely but it seems so), and in terms of usage, there doesn't seem to be any significant difference. If anyone knows of a solution, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue: I found out that the default Timer I used to check the Caps Lock status does not work in Secure Desktop. Due to the nature of Secure Desktop, I was unable to use the debugging function of the development environment to verify this, which led me to misunderstand that the API was blocked by secure desktop.

Why does the Timer not work? Is it because it runs in a separate thread?
Anyway, the problem has been solved. Thank you all.

Comment: Some Timer APIs (for example the old-school Win32 `SetTimer` API function) don't handle callbacks directly, they result in window messages.  (DefWndProc invokes callbacks when the timer message bubbles to it).  It's reasonable that delivery of window messages might be affected by switching the local session to the secure desktop.